# Custom rewrite permalink doesn't work

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

```
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'events',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Events' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Event' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%city%/events'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

register_taxonomy('cities', array('events'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'city' ),
  ));

function wpa_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'events' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'cities' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%city%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

The permalink are correctly structured (ex. `http://www.example.org/new-york/events/event-name`) but I have two issues:

- The template single-events.php is not taken and it shows 404.
- Same for the archive template. `http://www.example.org/new-york/events` should display the archive.

How to solve?

Comment: Have you flushed your rewrite rules? i.e. Settings > Permalinks > Save

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try replacing all instances of `%city%` with `%cities%`

Comment: I did and it seems it works. Why is that? I thought that `%city%` was just a placeholder with a random name. Even the archive page seems working now! Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%cities%` (matching the name of the taxonomy).

> I thought that %city% was just a placeholder with a random name.

Not quite - it's called a permalink structure (permastruct) and is used to map to a regular expression. When you call `register_taxonomy`, it automatically registers a new permastruct with the same name as the taxonomy.

Read up on [`WP_Rewrite::add_permastruct`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/add_permastruct/) which hopefully gives a bit more insight.

**Update**: Let's clarify what we're aiming for:

- `/city/new-york/events/` - All `events` posts attached to `new-york`
- `/city/new-york/restaurants/` - All `restaurants` posts attached to `new-york`
- `/city/new-york/events/foobar/` - Single `events` "foobar"

And do you need hierarchical slugs for `cities`? i.e. `england/london` (answering "yes" is going to make things difficult). Or is `london` sufficient?

**Update 2**: How about?

- `/events/new-york/` - All `events` posts attached to `new-york`
- `/restaurants/new-york/` - All `restaurants` posts attached to `new-york`
- `/restaurants/new-york/foobar/` - Single `events` "foobar"

Comment: Thanks but there's a catch. The taxonomy "cities" is used for different types of custom post types, for example `events` and `restaurants`. If I go to `/new-york/events` o `/new-york/restaurants`, the results are the same and are all the posts associated at the taxonomy `new-york`. How can I fix?

Comment: If I'm honest, I would advise you to rethink your permalink structure. The problem is outside the scope of this question, which is that you've got rules that are too vague/broad and are catching URLs intended for others. Ideally you want to swap `%cities%/events` to `events/%cities%`, which will probably go against everything you're aiming for, but means the CPT rules are now "namespaced" by `events` and won't get caught by your tax rules.

Comment: Yes honestly I'm having lot of troubles doing this on WP. I'm doing something very simple but it seems that it's very hard if not impossible to do it with WP. Basically I want to achieve a permalink structure like this: `/<city-name>/<custom-post-type>/<post-name>/`. So I can have `/new-york/events/`, `/chicago/restaurants/`, etc. Do you think is it possible with WP?

Comment: Let's clarify what you need (see updated answer).

Comment: Nope, I don't need hierarchical slugs. `london` is sufficient. What you wrote in the list is right, I'm aiming exactly for that structure and if you'll help me achieving it, I'll be forever grateful, this is giving me such an hard time. PS: I would like to omit the part `/city/` in the slug and start directly with the name of the city for example `www.example.com/new-york/etc`.

Comment: "I would like to omit the part `city/` in the slug" I was worried you might say so - _that's_ where things get really tricky (there's no "identifier" to capture the rule). Are you willing to compromise and have `/city`? Otherwise what about the alternative I've proposed in the question.

Comment: For me it would be ok to have `/events/new-york/` but the problem is that in the designing of the website I thought about having a front page for the current selected city at `example.com/new-york/` or `example.com/chicago/`. Said so, I think it might be better if we follow the `/city/..` option, what you think?

Comment: Is this essentially the main purpose of the website (events & restaurants in various locations). Or is it just a tiny section? Because if it's the former I would opt for Update 2. In fact thinking about it, I think Update 2 is a better URL structure regardless (IMO).

Comment: Events, restaurants and probably another custom post type related to the city, for example parks, or bars. But yeah, this is the purpose of the website. Reference website with multiple cities. I thought about rewriting the website with a framework for the headaches that WP is giving me but it would be such a very waste of time and I would lose all the facilities that WP gives to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41461/discussion-between-fred-collins-and-thedeadmedic).

Comment: Sorry I've had to leave my desk will get back to you when I can

Comment: Why do you think that Update 2 is a better URL structure? Anyway for me it might be ok, but then how to setup the front page I was talking about before at `example.com/new-york`? I would just create a static page for every city, right?